# Logger not working Elixir

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to use the `Logger.debug/1` for my web-project. I am unable to get past this error message even though I did make additions to the configuration file (config.exs) present in /myApp/config.

```
** (CompileError) web/controllers/api/app_controller.ex:36: you must require Logger before invoking the macro Logger.debug/1
```

I added this particular configuration at the end.

```
  config :logger,
    backends: [:console],
    compile_time_purge_level: :info
```

I took help to make this addition from http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/logger/Logger.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add `require Logger` in your module definition, e.g. right after `defmodule AAA...`

For example: https://github.com/22cans/exsyslog/blob/2b9ea2be7d7fcc17eab061425b6cd4fad8643996/examples/example1/lib/example1.ex

Answer (score 1):

Got it ! The reason why it didn't work because Logger was not found in the same module. So one has to import the module and functions in-order to use them.

So I used

```
require Logger
```

and this solved the problem. The program started working again.

Comment: I think Zepplock's answer covers this nicely.

Comment: I agree @onoriocatenacci